# Drupal 7 link node to basic page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

Ok I'll try to explain a little better.

I have created a view to display 3 items of a certain content type on homepage.

When I click each piece of content it takes me to actual content eg node22.

I need to be able to change this so when content on homepage is clicked it goes to a specific url alias I have already setup eg contact us page.

Any idea what I need to achieve this??

Comment: Are you showing teasers, fields etc in the view?

Answer (score 0):

We really need more info on your view to answer this but here are some thoughts.

If your display type is content the title automatically links to the node page so I will assume this is not what your issue is.

If you are using fields view just select the checkbox that says: "Link this field to the original piece of content". It is available in most "node" fields such as nid and title.

From above your example is how to "link node 49 to education page" You may be just needing the path module for that. Enable the core path module and then visit the node page you want to set a custom url for. Their should be a tab called "URL Path Settings" at the bottom of the page. Spice those up a bit more by downloading and installing the path auto module and the node url wil automatically be set when you create it.